# PHP pass random data in .user.ini

Tags: environment-variables, php

Can I use a PHP 5.3 .user.ini file to pass information other than existing PHP settings? E.g.
display_errors = On
include_path = /usr/myapp/classes
myapp_config_dir = /usr/myapp/config # <-- this is not a PHP setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good opportunity to create your own ini file and use [parse_ini_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to read it.